# How to disable the default F1 key behaviour in cobalt?

Tags: cobalt

In the cobalt browser, when I press the F1 key, the browser automatically pop up a DevTools window. There are the following information in this window: Cobalt.Lifetime, DevTools.Server, Event.Duration.MainWebModule.keyDown etc. We want to disable this F1 key behaviour. Can anyone tell us how to change the cobalt source code to disable this F1 key behaviour?

Answer (score 2):

The debug console will automatically be disabled when you do a production build of Cobalt (i.e. "gold"), however it is enabled for debug, devel and QA builds.

However, if you *really* want to completely disable it, even in development builds, you can find the code for handling "F1" key presses here: https://cobalt.googlesource.com/cobalt/+/master/src/cobalt/browser/browser_module.cc#1109

Comment: Like Andrew mentioned, please avoid making changes to the Cobalt code unless it's really necessary. In this case, F1 key would not affect users anyways.